# How to get particular value from JSON using php

Tags: php, json

I have run the below code

```
$api_key = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$api_url = "http://sms.eduapp.com:8381/app/miscapi/".$api_key."/getBalance/true/";
$credit_balance = file_get_contents( $api_url);
echo $credit_balance;
```

**And got output**

```
   [{"ROUTE_ID":"101057","ROUTE":"SMSWAY_TRANS","BALANCE":"13700"}]
```

From the above output I just want to get value 13700 in php variable.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: use json_decode as `$array = json_decode('[{"ROUTE_ID":"101057","ROUTE":"SMSWAY_TRANS","BALANCE":"13700"}]');

echo $array[0]->BALANCE ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$credit_balance = file_get_contents($api_url);
$balance = json_decode($credit_balance, true);
echo $balance[0]['BALANCE'];
```

Or:

```
$credit_balance = file_get_contents($api_url);
$balance = json_decode($credit_balance);
echo $balance[0]->BALANCE
```

Comment: The first example won't work (wrong variable in `echo`)

Comment: Thanks @jeprubio I have just remove true from the second example and it's work :)

Comment: Yes, sorry, the second parameter is to return it as associative array if it's true or as an object if it's not. Fixed both ways

Answer (score 1):

the site return you an array 
try this

```
$api_key = 'XXXXXXXXX';
$api_url = "http://sms.eduapp.com:8381/app/miscapi/".$api_key."/getBalance/true/";
$credit = file_get_contents( $api_url);
// sorry im forgot to decode th json
$credit_balance = json_decode($credit, true);
echo $credit_balance['BALANCE'];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick help but showing only    [   nothing else

Comment: try new code and tell us result

Comment: it's now working perflcly thanks for your help :) $balance = json_decode($credit_balance);
echo $balance[0]->BALANCE;